# Email Reciepient to change every 6 months MOSS 2007

Tags: workflow, email

I am doing this project to send email reminder to admin. But I want to make this admin changes every 6 months? is there anyway to change email reciepient every 6 months by using sharepoint workflow without using the initiator?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is save the Admin to a list item and in the workflow get the value of the user from the List Item instead of hard-coding that in the workflow...

When the admin change after 6 month, you will just need to update the List item...

I hope I got the question correct!

Answer (score 0):

i was working on the same requirement. What we can do is create a application page and get the congifuration details from admin . It will accessable across the server farm so that you can get the application content in sequential workflow. hope this helps you...

thanks